# How well-behaved are the operations of mapping a matrix to the $S$ or $N$ part of the $S+N$ decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the maps $S,N \colon \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{C}) $ taking a matrix to the $S$ or $N$ part of the $S+N$ decomposition. How well-behaved are these maps? Are they e.g. continuous/Lipschitz/differentiable/smooth/holomorphic, and if not (which I suppose is the case), do they satisfy some weaker versions of these properties? What about all the other properties one could consider?

Comment: Do $S$ and $N$ refer to semisimple and nilpotent matrices respectively?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Yes, exactly, as in the $S+N$ decomposition.

Comment: The two facts that (1) almost all matrices have distinct eigenvalues and therefore have $N=0$ and that (2) some matrices have $N\neq0$ suffice to answer the question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Fine, then look at the subset where $N \neq 0$. Does it have any nice properties there? I asked for nice, weaker versions of these properties.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to answer this, but this is also often called the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition so you may be able to use that term in your search.

Comment: @Gaussler: That restriction won't help you -- for example, that subset contains all 4×4 matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\&&A\end{pmatrix}$, so there'll still be discontinuities when $A$ hits the subset of non-diagonalizable 2×2 blocks.

Comment: The decomposition maps might possibly be well-behaved on each class of matrices with the same sizes of the Jordan blocks.